# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, joomla, whmcs

I am using `WHMCS` as a billing system and `J!WHMCS` to wrap my joomla website with the joomla header and footer and basic styling...
But it seems on certain pages, namely the invoices page I get the following error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in

and this is causing my online chat function to bomb out on these pages...

Does anybody have any idea what I can do to resolve this.
I did check if I disable the Joomla wraping, it does not give the error, meaning the error must come from my joomla files (`jquery.min.js:2`)

Comment: Did you look at the stacktrace and see where it is triggered in your code?

Comment: This can be anything. Without more info such as the suggested stack trace it is almost impossible to say where things go wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to follow up - as the J!WHMCS developer, this issue is caused by WHMCS using v 1.10.5 of the dataTables javascript in combination with jQuery 1.11.3.  The best course of action is to upgrade the dataTables library to at least 1.10.7 as that will work with jQuery 1.11.3.  The harder course is to downgrade jQuery in Joomla... not an easy task.

Actually I think I helped the OP via a ticket earlier this week lol  Hope this is of help.